# How to add items which contains in loop and adding into the array?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```js
Reducers

const initialState = {
  plateArrayObject: []
};
export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case "REORDER_SEQUENCING_GET_PLATE_DATA":
  let initialData = action.data;
  let plateArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < initialData.length; i++) {
    let temp = [
      initialData[i]["name"],
      initialData[i]["ordered_date"],
      "Reorder"
    ];
    plateArray.push(temp);
  }
  return { ...state, plateArrayObject: plateArray };
    default:
      return state;
```

Here the snippet of the redux array,And adding the items into the plateArray but it will mutates the array.
Could some one let me know how to adding items into the Array in immutable way.Means here I want to add items into the plateArray using immutable.
could some one paste the snippets
it would be helpful.

Comment: can you expound more what you are trying to achieve in your reducer, and could you show us the structure of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use slice() function which creates a shallow copy, hence it will keep immutability intact.

Like

```
return { ...state, plateArrayObject: plateArray.slice() };
```